# How to count rows from a different table during same SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, union

I would like to get all the jobs for a person, and count all the bids he received which is stored in a different table.

I have one table with following rows:
`table jobs: jobId,userid,title`

And a different table with the following:
`table bids: jobId,amount`

Now I want to get all the jobs from the first table `jobs WHERE userid=1` and combine this with counting all rows in the second table `table bids` that have the same `jobId` for each job (line) that is found from the first table.

A possible output could be:

```
job.jobId        job.userid       job.title       bids.Total
 1                  10            "My job"            20
 2                  11            "Other job"         5
```

I know how to do it the **wrong way**, which is like this:

```
$stmt0 = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt0->prepare("SELECT jobId,title FROM jobs WHERE userid=?");
$stmt0->bind_param('i', $userid);
$stmt0->execute();
$stmt0->bind_result($jobId,$title);

// Fetch the result of the query
while($stmt0->fetch()) { 

$ary = "SELECT amount FROM bids WHERE jobId='$jobId'";
if ($stmt_1 = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $ary)) {
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_1);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt_1);
    $total_bids = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt_1);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt_1);
}

// show all jobs with total bids
...

 }


$stmt0->close();
```

How can I do this with one query?

Comment: maybe ... `SELECT jobs.jobId, job.user_id, job.title, sum(bids.Total) 'bids' from jobs INNER JOIN bids ON bids.jobId = jobs.jobId WHERE job.user_id=? GROUP BY jobs.jobId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Join a count and  group by

```
     SELECT a.jobId,a.userid, a.title, count(b.jobid) as bidsTotal 
     FROM jobs as a
     inner join bids as b on b.jobId = a.JobId
     WHERE userid=?
     Group by  a.jobId,a.userid, a.title
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it was easier than I thought!

Comment: I actually noticed one issue, if they are no bids it will always return 1. Any solution to this?

Comment: Found it, change to count(b.jobId)

Comment: @Nicolas: The query would need to use an **outer** join in order to return zero counts. The inner join will only return rows from `jobs` where there is a matching row in `bids`, and the equality predicate (condition) on `b.jobId` will guarantee that `b.jobId` won't be null... the only way this query returns a "zero" count is if the inner join is changed to an outer join.

Answer (score 1):

You could emulate the current "wrong way" approach in a single query, using correlated subquery in the SELECT list, so you would have just one query:

```
 SELECT j.jobId
      , j.title
      , j.userid
      , ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM bids b 
           WHERE b.jobId = j.jobId
        ) AS cnt_bids
   FROM jobs j
  WHERE j.userid = ?
  ORDER BY j.jobId
```

The correlated subquery will get executed for every row returned by the outer query. This approach gets expensive if the outer query returns a large number of rows.

If there is a column (or set of columns) that are UNIQUE in the `jobs` table, we can get an equivalent result using an OUTER JOIN operation and a GROUP BY.

If we have a guarantee that `jobId` is UNIQUE in the `jobs` table, an equivalent result can be obtained using an outer join operation

```
 SELECT j.jobId
      , j.title
      , j.userid
      , COUNT(b.jobId) AS cnt_bids
   FROM jobs j
   LEFT
   JOIN bids b
     ON b.jobId = j.jobId
  WHERE j.userid = ?
 GROUP BY j.jobId, j.title, j.userid 
 ORDER BY j.jobId
```

Comment: Thanks! The second option did the job

Comment: The second approach, using an outer join (`LEFT JOIN`) and an aggregate (`COUNT`) will work when we have a column (or group of columns) that is guaranteed to be unique, so we can specify a `GROUP BY` operation. (The outer join will allow us to return zero counts when there are no matching rows in `bids`.). If we don't have a uniqueness guarantee (a more general case), then we can fall back to the correlated subquery to return the specified result.  (In terms of performance, both approaches will benefit when the suitable indexes are available.)